# Robustness to deviation from normality with regularized VAR model - references

Tags: references, normality-assumption, regularization, vector-autoregression

I was listening to a talk where the presenter was talking about using regularized estimation approaches in a VAR(1) model $$X_t = \Gamma X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Omega).$$ The claim was put forth that deviations from normality assumptions, e.g. that in this setting are less of a problem because of the regularization approach. Is this true in general? I have performed a reference search in Google as well as Google Scholar but could not really find anyhting. Is there any general theory about regularization with respect to deviations from normality?

Comment: What do you mean by "in general"? If you mean "for any unspecified form of regularization whatever" then no. If you mean some particular kind or kinds of relgularization, we'd at least need to know what kind(s).

Comment: Could this question be reduced from the whole VAR model to just one equation of the VAR model? If regularization is applied to each equation separately, then analysing one equation would be sufficient. Then it would be possible to generalize to any multiple regression model instead of a particular VAR equation. Then the question would be, *is regularized estimation of a multiple linear regression model more robust to non-normality than non-regularized estimation*? If so, it should be easier to find a reference since now the subject is broader than the original one. Does that make sense?

Comment: Normality is only useful for small sample inference. Inference after regularization is quite problematic (it is an active research area with no trivial results for now). Then what can be regularization useful for where normality is needed? I fail to see a connection.

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard Hardy said in a comment, this is an area of active research. But there is a book with a chapter dedicated to the topic (chapter 6), so you could start with having a look at [sparsity-book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498712169).